# Use pivot table to represent array of object data

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, pivot-table

I'm trying to use pivot table to represent the following data,

```
$.pivotUtilities.tipsData=[
              {status:"open",year:2014,value:100.00},
              {status:"open",year:2015,value:200.00},
              {status:"open",year:2016,value:300.00},
              {status:"approved",year:2016,value:10.00},
              {status:"approved",year:2015,value:20.00},
              {status:"approved",year:2014,value:30.00},
              {status:"closed",year:2016,value:3.00},
              {status:"closed",year:2014,value:3.00},
              {status:"closed",year:2013,value:-10.00}
              ]   

    var utils = $.pivotUtilities;

    $("#output").pivot(
      utils.tipsData, {
        rows: ["status"],
        cols: ["year"],
        vals: ["value"]
      });
```

I get the following result

[image]

but I need to represent the value not number of values for each status,like this image
[image]

Can anyone help me to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is angular there is no need to implement a jQuery plugin when all you need to do is map your data in controller to new structure and pass that to view to accomplish this fairly simple table

```
  $scope.pivotFields = ['open', 'approved', 'closed'];
  $scope.pivotData  = {};

  angular.forEach(data, function(item) {
    if (!$scope.pivotData[item.year]) {
      $scope.pivotData[item.year] = {open: 0, approved: 0, closed: 0}
    }
    $scope.pivotData[item.year][item.status] += item.value;       
  });

  $scope.years = Object.keys($scope.pivotData).sort(function(a,b){
     return b-a;
  });
```

View:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Status</th>
      <th ng-repeat="yr in years">{{yr}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="field in pivotFields">
      <td>{{field}}</td>
      <td ng-repeat="yr in years">{{pivotData[yr][field]}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/miBjvOcueQqaC6k4fKqW?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following code

```
$("#output").pivotUI(financial, {
            rows: ["requeststateName"],
            cols: ["fiscalyearValue"],
            aggregatorName: "Integer Sum",
            vals: ["amountrequested"],
            rendererName: "Heatmap"
        });
```